# Ставится ли запятая после вспомогательных наречий "в итоге" и "а после"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Но в итоге он смог добиться протекции,
>   получить необходимый опыт работы,
>   а после поступить в элитный университет
>   для получения степени магистра.

Если нельзя поставить запятую после "в итоге" и "а после", то почему, потому что кто-то сказал что так делать нельзя, или есть более разумные причины так не делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Разумные причины таковы.**

1) **Мы ставим запятые не тогда, когда нам хочется это сделать**, то есть для обозначения произносительных пауз. В этом случае весь текст был бы "украшен" запятыми, которые ничего, кроме этих пауз,  не обозначали бы и не имели бы никакого смысла.

2) **Русская пунктуация основана на трех принципах: семантическом, грамматическом и интонационном** (первый относится к содержанию текста, а второй и третий к его форме). Автор хочет выразить определенное содержание и подбирает для этого подходящую форму: строит грамматику и структуру предложения. В устной речи каждому варианту соответствует своя интонация, и знаки препинания помогают нам правильно определить эту интонационно-грамматическую форму.

Заданное предложение

**Но в итоге он смог добиться протЕкции, получить необходимый опыт рабОты, а после поступить в элитный университет для получения степени магИстра.**

**Это простое предложение**, осложненное тремя однородными сказуемыми, и предложение тоже состоит из трех фраз, каждая из которых имеет фразовое (тоническое) ударение. Запятые также делят его на  три части. Таким образом, семантика, грамматика и интонация соответствуют друг другу.

**Выделенные наречия играют вспомогательную роль** (это своеобразные маркеры): они или связывают предложение с предыдущим текстом (В ИТОГЕ), или уточняют время  (А ПОСЛЕ ― союз А  и временное наречие). Разумеется, **нельзя отделять их запятой от тех фраз, к которым они относятся.**

**Итак, первый шаг**  ― это определение грамматики предложения. Знаки препинания обозначают только те паузы, которые имеют грамматическое обоснование.

Comment: Сеятель знанья на ниву народную! Сейте **разумное**, доброе, вечное! :))

Comment: Думаете, не стоит зря тратить время? Понимаете, это принципиальный вопрос. Я полагаю, что практически все пользователи  русского языка, изучая правила постановки знаков препинания, убеждены в том, что "кто-то так сказал их  ставить".  Просто они молча принимают такую ситуацию, но есть и "бунтари", которые требуют объяснений. В конечном итоге именно такие люди способны к творческому подходу к жизни и к переменам, к движению вперед.  Я не уверена, что ситуацию можно изменить в ближайшее время и пишу скорее для будущих читателей, хотя и не уверена, что письмо дойдет до адресата.

Comment: Jasmin, Вы почувствовали улыбку в моем комментарии, но это была улыбка одобрения. Я верю, что не прападет Ваш труд.

Comment: Спасибо. Знаете, я не первый год отвечаю на вопросы на сайтах русского языка, но меня всегда спрашивают одно и то же: как писать, какое правило? И ни разу никто не спросил,  откуда взялось это правило, на чем оно основано. И я знаю почему. Люди считают, что правила - это только средство унификации и соблюдения единого порядка в письме и что  составлены они по принципу взаимного соглашения, а не  по своей внутренней логике. Наверное, в других языках так оно и есть, но русский язык в этом отношении особенный.